# Is it possible run makemigrations with deleted schema?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, schema

My all SQL schema was deleted cause of windows10 initialization.
So, I wanna run makemigrations with already existing django project code(with so many lines......).
But "python manage.py makemigrations" not works with error 'Table doesn't exist'... Is there some methods overcome these situations ???

Answer (score 2):

Your existing migrations scripts are corrupt. So you need to do the following steps:

1. Delete the migrations folder inside your app
2. Then run makemigrations

   ```
   python manage.py makemigrations
   ```
3. Apply the changes to DB

   ```
   python manage.py migrate
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :- ) ! But this solution not worked in my case, I just use sql remote connection, Thanks!!

Comment: Ok good. You can post an answer how you resolved and accept the same.